# BeautifulSoup - Can't get tbody

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-tbody

I'm trying to get a table that is located inside multiple nests.
I'm new to Beautifulsoup and I have practiced some simple eeemples.
The issue is that, I can't understand why my code can't get the "div" tag that has the class "Explorer is-embed".
Because from that point, I can go deeper to get to the tbody where all the data that I want to **scrape** are located.
thanks for your help in advance.

Below is my code:

```
url = "https://ourworldindata.org/covid-cases"
url_content = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_content.text, "lxml")
########################
div1 = soup3.body.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"content-wrapper"})
div2 = div1[0].find_all("div", attrs={"class":"offset-content"})
sections = div2[0].find_all('section')
figure = sections[1].find_all("figure")
div3 = figure[0].find_all("div")
div4 = div3[0].find_all("div")
```

Here is a snapshot of the "div" tag that I'm not getting.
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4mb1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Data is dynamically loaded. Instead, grab the public source csv (other formats available)

https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-source-data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv')
df.head()
```

Values you see in the **Daily new confirmed COVID-19 cases (per 1M)**
table are calculated from the same data as in that file for the two dates being compared e.g.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this not the table I was looking for. the one I was looking for is entitled "Daily new confirmed COVID-19 cases (per 1M)" and you can scroll to it by clicking on the "Table" tab.

Comment: They are calculated from the data in that file.

Comment: Thanks for your  answer, but this doesn't answer my question. My primary concern is that I can't get the table I'm lookin for using Beatifulsoup.

Comment: And I am telling you the data is pulled dynamically from that csv. Check the network tab of the browser. It is fetched by a js script which I assume handles the calculations.

Comment: In the first part of my answer I tell you that the data is dynamically loaded via javascript. Perhaps I should have made it more clear that you therefore cannot get it from the url you are trying as javascript does not run with requests. You need to either use selenium, or track down the data source. My answer gives you the data source. The same source csv the page uses to dynamically load the content you want.

Comment: I have given you an answer. The only thing I haven't done is replicate all the calculations the page does and present it in the same format. All the data you require is present in that csv. I have shown you how to perform one of the calculations to help you.

Comment: Thanks for you r time but these are not the answers I was looking for. I could have downloaded each table. My challnge is not with Pandas but with Beautifulsoup. Since this can be done using Selenium, I'll try to see how my issue can be sorted out.